# Best practice to check data of a user before logging in

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4, security

There is a table that keeps a user's details. An admin can lock this user by setting the column called locked. Once the user is locked they cannot login. I am using The WebSecurity.Login to login. As of now I am letting the user to login, then it checks if they are not locked and if they are instead of home page they are redirected to locked page.

**What is the best practice that I can use so that the user doesnt gets logged in, check the field and gets redirected. This is in MVC 4**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand you.. but currently you have something like this:

```
Membership.LoginUser(userName, password);

if (CurrentUser.IsLocked) {
    RedirectUser();
}
```

..can you not just replace it with something like this?:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(userName, password);
if (user.IsLocked) {
    Redirect();
}
else {
    Membership.LoginUser(user);
}
```

... ?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. So this will pull in the whole user data before logging in. I tried that too. But is it the best way, I mean if there exists any security issues with it? Just to know!

Comment: How else do you envision being able to check the `IsLocked` field?  The other option is a single field entity that just holds that field.. although it isnt required.

Comment: it seems I ve to go with either 1 of the above, thank you so very much +1 for ur help, sorry i cannot upvote you answer for now but i ll do it as soon as i get myself the privilege to do [havent earned myself 15 points]..

Comment: +1, both are neat solutions just to mention first approach will require one DB where as second one will require 2 db hits in case of successfull login. Also as AJ states he is allowing user to login and take him to locked page first one is better approach.